# Android - Launching Main Settings Activity not always working

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY is not working for starting android settings activity (android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS)

I have an activity from which I start Android Settings Window (android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS). I do it like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
activityContext.startActivity(intent);
```

It usually works. However, when I follow these steps:

1) launch settings from my activity
2) go further (i.e. Wireless & networks), 
3) press home, etc
3) launch my activity again
4) launch settings from my activity
5) then 'Wireless & networks' screen appears instead of main android settings activity!

I also tried:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
activityContext.startActivity(intent);
```

But it's not working either. Do you know what might be the problem? I wanted to add that flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY works for my internal activities.

Comment: @Jonas I would like to make a widget that will always start main settings activity (and it sometimes launches some subsettings activities).

Comment: Then do not put the NO_HISTORY flag :) I am still not sure sure I understood

Comment: @Jonas I use NO_HISTORY for settings, because i want to remove it from history stack every time user navigates away from it.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

Use Case:
1) User launches settings and goes to Wireless submenu. Then he navigates away from settings (home button).
2) User presses my widget after a few hours (to run settings). I do not want Android to launch Wireless submenu and thats why i use NO_HISTORY flag. It works great with activities from my application.

Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` to the intent.