# code to show settings screen in Android Tablet 4.0.4 after button click

Tags: android

I want to invoke settings screen through code in my Android Tablet 4.0.4.

i did not find any code to show settings screen for Android tablets.

Please give me solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
@Pavan.

Comment: what do You mean, the android device settings or Your own settings in Your app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496650/android-launching-main-settings-activity-not-always-working

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open Settings of Android Phone on a button click in our Android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966308/how-to-open-settings-of-android-phone-on-a-button-click-in-our-android-app)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the lines below:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS));
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS));
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS));
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS));
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS));
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

And there are more options.

Comment: Put any one of above lines in your button onClick() method

Comment: Accept my answer , if it is really useful because other can use it

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.Global));
```

With this line of code, the main settings screen will be invoked.